# No wireless or wired internet after installing kubuntu-desktop on 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, kubuntu, network-manager, ethernet

I installed the kubuntu-desktop package on a normal Ubuntu install, but beforehand set up a TimeShift snapshot in case I wanted to undo the install. I logged into kubuntu but it was unable to connect to the internet. After restoring the TimeShift snapshot, I still was unable to connect---neither on my elementary OS dual boot nor on a liveUSB session.

It always seems to fail on "getting IP configuration." Here are the results of some commands:

$ ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:03:9a:f1:3b:18
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea03:9aff:fef1:3b18/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:161 (161.0 B)  TX bytes:54669 (54.6 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11881 (11.8 KiB)  TX bytes:11881 (11.8 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:85:08:c1:05:20
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

$ nm-tool

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connecting
- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] --------------------------------------------------
Type:              Wired
Driver:            r8169
State:             connecting (getting IP configuration)
Default:           no
HW Address:        E8:03:9A:F1:3B:18

Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes
  Speed:           100 Mb/s

Wired Properties
  Carrier:  on


- Device: wlan0  --------------------------------------------------
Type:              802.11 WiFi
Driver:            iwlwifi
State:             disconnected
Default:           no
HW Address:        C4:85:08:C1:05:20

Capabilities:

Wireless Properties
  WEP Encryption:  yes
  WPA Encryption:  yes
  WPA2 Encryption: yes

Wireless Access Points
  madrivante:      Infra, 00:0C:F6:A0:B4:7A, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 73 WPA WPA2
  UPC244623609:    Infra, DC:71:44:FC:3A:B8, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 95 WPA2
  ALEXANDRA:       Infra, C0:3F:0E:68:C0:26, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 95 WPA WPA2
```

$ ping -c 3 www.google.com

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

$ ping -c 3 8.8.8.8

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

$ sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network
  description: Wireless interface
  product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
  logical name: wlan0
  version: 24
  serial: c4:85:08:c1:05:20
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
  resources: irq:45 memory:f1500000-f1501fff
*-network
  description: Ethernet interface
  product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
  vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
  logical name: eth0
  version: 06
  serial: e8:03:9a:f1:3b:18
  size: 100Mbit/s
  capacity: 1Gbit/s
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
  configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
  resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1404000-f1404fff memory:f1400000-f1403fff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was not my computer but rather the router (just did a restart). The router wasn't able to allocate new IP addresses, so eventually every device on the network would have been affected but my computer was the first.